# Uploading attachments in Salesforce1 Mobile?

Tags: salesforce1-app

Has anyone seen a solution to take a local attachment file (PDF, PPT, etc) from a mobile device and upload it and attach it to a chatter feed in Salesforce1 Mobile?

Current chatter limits allow access to the camera roll and 'Salesforce Files' to share and post on a chatter thread.

Answer (score 1):

http://ccoenraets.github.io/salesforce1-app-tutorial/chatter-feed.html

Go to the page layout of the custom object you are trying to upload the attachment to, click edit, under Publisher Actions, click "Override global publisher actions," and you can now upload attachments to the custom object!

Thanks,

Brad

Comment: the File action mentioned in the post still seem to use only the images from camera / gallery. but the question is about uploading other files stored in the mobile device to chatter. is it possible with the file action ?

Answer (score 0):

from an Iphone, you need to open that file using Salesforce1 first. It will then be available in the "salesforce files" list when you choose to attach it.