# How to add Notes and attachments to the Opportunity in Salesforce1 mobile

Tags: salesforce1-app, administration

In the desktop I am able to see "Notes & Attachments" related list on the Opportunity. But When looking the same opportunity in Mobile (Salesforce1) not able to see Notes & Attachment.

How to enable that in mobile Can anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes are now available in salesforce1 but not attachments. See the idea delivered in winter 16: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bpd6AAC

Answer (score 0):

Files and [new] Notes (2 separate related lists) are successors for this:

> Salesforce1 supports documents that are uploaded through the Files action OR through Chatter. Documents and any attachments uploaded through the Notes and Attachments section on a record list view aren't guaranteed to be accessible in Salesforce1

[Support for notes, documents, files and attachments in Salesforce1](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000206009&language=en_US)

You can also set `Files uploaded to the Attachments related list on records are uploaded as Salesforce Files, not as attachments` for compatibility - [read more](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_files_notes_attachments_list.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply  I added File and new note action on Page layout. Able to see New Note on action bar but not able to see File

Comment: See if [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/42172/12440) can be helpful. I'm not using Salesforce1, so can't recommend anything ((